# How to check Windows 10 media version?

Tags: windows-10

With all the [back and forth of version 1511 (aka Threshold 2) being withdrawn and then re-enabled via the Media Creation Tool](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326), how can I check the version MCT has downloaded (and created an ISO for)? `bootmgr` from the image is dated 10/30/2015. Does that mean I have version 1511 in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more detailed build version can be seen from the File Version of setup.exe, or for perhaps more understandable info, check the content of idbwinfo.txt inside the sources folder. The ISO I got have the build number 10586, just the same as the File Version number, and the idbwinfo contain the "th2_release" text.

Comment: Thanks; it turns they actually have an article on that on the MS wiki, but I failed to find it before: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-verify-if-you-downloaded-or-installed-the/06f98274-741a-45df-9e0d-6cc48816824b The part on MCT is in the 2nd half of that page.

Comment: i'd be interested in knowing if win10 is home or pro but this doesn't say

Comment: @barlop if we're talking about ISO, after 1511 the ISO is universal, the media creator option only ask for architecture